# Бан на php...

Tags: php

Помогите с выводом бана.

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$file = "ips.dat";
$ban = file($file);
$count = count($ban);  for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {  if($ip == $ban[$i])
 { die("I'm sorry, you've been banned. $ip"); }  }
```

Вставляю этот код в начало, но он не помогает... Нужно, чтобы, если if выполнялось выводилась запись о бане, если нет, далее по коду выполнялись скрипты.

Comment: Формат файла не был бы лишним. Просто адреса, каждый на строчке?

Comment: да, каждый на строчке... так записывать удобно через форму.

Comment: отредактируйте код до читаемого вида, 4 пробела в начале строки или выделить код и нажать кнопку "101010"

Answer (score 2):

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$file = "{$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]}/ips.dat"; // у меня файл в корне лежал
$ban = file($file);
$count = count($ban);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    if ($ip == trim($ban[$i])) {
        die("I'm sorry, you've been banned. $ip");
    }
}
```

Просто добавил trim - всё работает.

Comment: echo $ban[$i]; <<< стоит убрать данную строчку

Comment: Да, спасибо, просто тестил, у меня осталась.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
$fp = fopen("ips.dat", "r");
$my_ips='';
if ($fp) 
{
 while (!feof($fp))
 {
  $my_ips. = fgets($fp, 999);
 }
if (preg_match("/$ip/",$my_ips)!=0) die("I'm sorry, you've been banned. $ip");
}else echo 'Ошибка открытия файла!';
fclose($fp);
```

Пробуйте. мне такая реализация чесно нравится больше чем построчное сравнение)

Comment: а чем они отличаются? скоростью выполнения?

Comment: Я кстати подумал, что этот должен быть быстрее... т.к. не читается сразу весь файл построчно, но оказалось, что скорость этого даже чуть-чуть медленнее, если ip забаненного стоит в конце и сильно медленнее, если в начале файла. Для 2000 ip адресов (собственный ip идёт последним в списке) это примерно 0.002 против 0.0017, а если первой строчкой, то 0.002 против 0.00048...
Если заменить 999 на 40, то чуть быстрей начинает работать.

Comment: различаются реализацией, в моем подходе можно с легкостью забивать целые подсети используя регулярки)
например 192.168.1.{2,4} будет все айпи от 192.168.1.0 до 192.168.1.255

Comment: интресно х)

Answer (score 0):

Зачем изобретать велосипед?

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$banlist = file_get_contents('ips.dat');
$search = strpos($banlist, $ip);
if ($search !== false)
die ("Вы забанены");
?>
```

Всё должно работать.

Comment: ага, только IP xxx.xxx.xxx.1 забанит треть подсети)

Comment: Бггг, банить по ip аще зло :)